# Find css class after parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there is any jquery which is find class after parent div, I am using class "trapezoid-two" and make jquery code but that create issue, so can any one tel me how to find css after parent div class('ban-menu1').

HTML:-

```
<div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
    <div class="ban-menu1"></div>
    <svg class="trapezoid-two" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%">
      <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="images/shade-two.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="100" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
      <path d="M0,0 L100,23 L100,77 L0,100z" fill="url(#img1)"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$( ".trapezoid-two" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z');
    $(this).parent().addClass('img-scale');     
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,23 L100,80 L0,100z');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('img-scale');
  }
);
});
```

Comment: no "col-md-2 nopadding" is a parent, and i have to find "ban-menu1" class or div

Comment: @BharatNegi see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ban-menu1` is a sibling of `.trapezoid-two` use `prev()` to help you add a class to it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// svg path change  
$( ".trapezoid-two" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z');
    $(this).prev().addClass('img-scale');     
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,23 L100,80 L0,100z');
    $(this).prev().removeClass('img-scale');
  }
);
```

see demo : https://jsfiddle.net/cgvbt80q/